# Reuse result of string comparison for faster std::sort

Tags: c++, string, sorting, predicate, strcmp

I want to sort a vector of unique strings with `strcmp`.

`std::sort` expects a predicate telling whether one string is less than the other, however `strcmp` actually already returns the relationship of the strings and it would actually be wise to make use of that information instead of loosing it.

This is useful because it additionally needs to be determined whether strings are equal - in this case the predicate will get called again with the same strings but in inverse argument order.

This is the naive way of sorting:

```
vector<const char*> cache;
sort(cache.begin(), cache.end(), [](const char* left, const char* right)
{
    return strcmp(left, right) < 0;
});
```

I am experimenting with the following idea, where I store the result of the comparison and reuse it if the same strings get compared again.

```
vector<const char*> cache;
sort(cache.begin(), cache.end(), [notLess = false, r = (const char*)nullptr](const char* left, const char* right) mutable
{
    // possibly reuse previous comparison of same strings passed in inverse order
    if (notLess &&
        r == left)
    {
        notLess = false;
        // always less since vector contains unique strings
        return true;
    }

    if (notLess = strcmp(left, right) >= 0)
        r = right;
    return !notLess;
});
```

In order to limit stored information and the number of additionally introduced comparisons, I thought of only storing the *right* string, which is becoming the left for the inverse comparison.

Now, my actual question is whether it is enough to check only the previously *right* string or do I need to store and check the previously *left* string as well?

Comment: The standard library may copy the predicate an any number of times.

Comment: _"it additionally needs to be determined whether strings are equal"_.  Are you saying that `std::sort` needs to determine that?   It doesn't.

Comment: Does std::sort ever call compare with the same arguments?  Have you checked?

Comment: `std::sort` cannot handle the three-way comparison `strcmp` is returning.  Use [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) instead.

Comment: *in this case the predicate will get called again with the same strings but in inverse argument order.* -- That is only done as far as I know in debug runtime implementations of `std::sort` where the runtime is checking to see if your predicate follows a *strict-weak-order*.   Otherwise you can't surmise what two items you will be getting in the predicate.

Comment: @stark - debug build versions of std::sort may do a one time check with arguments reversed to make sure comparison is < and not <= .

Comment: Comparing strings for less-than takes the same amount of time as comparing for equal. You won't gain anything, and you could easily come out behind with this scheme.

Comment: @HenriMenke `qsort` is primitive compared to `std::sort`, and is generally slower. Its ability to use a three-way comparison doesn't give it any advantages.

Comment: There will probably be a faster version of `std::sort` added if the spaceship operator is.  http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf

Comment: VS 2017's STL uses partition quicksort as part of its introsort, which performs a two-way comparison (, so my question is definitely a valid one - yes I checked that before. Thanks for bringing to my attention the potential copies of the predicate - however this doesn't impose a problem as it's only used if an optimization is possible - the intent is to leverage cached information only in the very specific case of comparing the same strings two-way.

Answer (score 3):

First off, your assumptions are wrong. `std::sort` is not going to call the comparison with the same arguments twice. As a result, the whole idea is flawed.

Second (and more importantly) your idea is flawed because predicates are not supposed to hold state. `std::sort` can copy those predicates and reuse the copies (in fact, gcc version certainly copied predicates when I checked some time ago) and thus will break the whole comparison.

Comment: Your statement isn't true: std::sort uses partitioned quick sort in the STL implementation that VS 2017 ships, and it uses two-way comparison. Second there's not happening anything illegal when copying the stateful predicate. The variables storing state are only used for optimization if possible. My question was specifically about whether it's safe to check only for one string to detect two-way comparison or whether I need to check both strings

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the case proposed here, the idea isn't useful as `sort` doesn't need to distinguish the exact equivalence - it may painlessly mix `a > b` and `a == b` cases (thank to the unspecified ordering of equivalent elements).

But, if we consider `stable_sort` instead, the idea **does** work. Stable sort actually needs to distinguish all the three cases: `a < b`, `a == b` and `a > b` so it will call `Cmp` functor twice.

In general, taking care of such an optimization is often reasonable, and in some cases it's absolutely necessary in order to avoid an exponential growth of computation time (for example, if you sort/search some multi-level container when you need to search through children levels before you know the result of upper level comparison).

Also, storing the results of string comparison may be useful for subsequent sort/search/insert operations. Of course in order to implement this efficiently one needs a fast random access container which doesn't require string character iteration (otherwise it will be worse in runtime complexity than mere `strcmp`). It may become possible if your strings are *canonicalized* first.